# override last-edit field auto-calculation in FileMaker 19

Tags: filemaker

I have a table that has auto-calculated fields for who (name) and when (date) the row was last changed, using the normal FileMaker field definitions and a protected field.

However, I have one use case where I copy data into this table, from a source that also has these entries, and I want to copy them as well. But when my script copies the data, it triggers the auto-calculation, and in the end, my "changed at" is set to the current time and "changed by" to the current user. I want to retain whatever my external source has in these fields.

How can I temporarily disable the auto-calculation for these fields in FileMaker, so that for the duration of my script, they act as normal fields and simply take the data I enter?

Comment: Can you import the data? When importing, you have the option to deactivate auto-enter options.

Comment: Not really an option here. I'm trying to synchronise data between two sources. Obviously, that sync should not count as a change, otherwise I have a never-ending sync-loop.

Comment: I don't see why that's "not really an option". The alternative is to use your own calculation formula and make an exception when a flag is turned on. Which is a lot of work.

Comment: I'm doing a two-way sync, that's why the normal import does not support my use case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your auto-entered modification fields as follows

- Switch to auto-enter Calculated value
- Switch 'Do not replace existing value of field (if any)' off

Then set the auto-enter calculation to something like the following

```
Let ( trigger = GetField ( "" ) ; If ( $$SilentSync > 0 ; Self ; Get ( CurrentDate ) ) )
```

You'll need to change the `Get ( CurrentDate )` to whatever is appropriate for that field, and you'll need to do this for all modification fields in every table.

After this these fields will work as normal during day-to-day editing etc.

When setting data during your sync you can use the following at the beginning of the sync process

```
Set Variable [$$SilentSync: 1]
```

Then clear $$SilentSync at the end of the sync process

```
Set Variable [$$SilentSync: ""]
```

Comment: that sounds like it'll do what I need. I've upvoted it for now, and will test it.

Comment: I'm experimenting with this and I don't understand what the first statement (let trigger) does and why it is needed.

Comment: Ah yes, that's the trick that this functionality revolves around. The calculation on this field needs to trigger any time any field in the record is modified. To achieve that you could reference every field from the calculation (and remember to add new fields to it whenever you added one to the table), however this is a pain. But using the function GetField ( "" ) with an empty string as the parameter does all the work for you. It causes the function to evaluate when any field is modified. After that you just need to include that function is some benign area of the calc, I chose a Let header

Comment: I've now built my solution around this idea and it works brilliantly. Thanks!

Comment: fun fact: This works to prevent updating the field via the UI, but not if I insert data via JDBC. Strangely, because I thought I had it working.