# avoid triggering auto-update and calculated fields when updating FileMaker data through JDBC

Tags: jdbc, filemaker

I have noticed two things I want to avoid when updating data in my FileMaker solution through JDBC:

1. field calculations are run while inserting/updating data, some of which considerably slow down the update process
2. last-modified fields are changed (but created fields are not, even on INSERT)

So I am looking for a way to update/insert through JDBC without triggering script triggers or the "changed on/by" auto-calculation. (because I am merging data from another DB and want the change fields to represent the actual last change, not the copy).

For case #2 I have tried both the built-in checkbox of changing the field when edited, and the calculated field solution with `Let ( trigger = GetField ( "" ) ; If ( $$SilentSync > 0 ; Self ; Get ( CurrentDate ) ) )` as was answered, e.g. in my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65667949/override-last-edit-field-auto-calculation-in-filemaker-19) about avoiding auto-calculations when working in the solution itself. Sadly, both get triggered (and the global variable solution doesn't avoid it) when using JDBC.

Is there a way to say "don't update this field when I change it via JDBC"? Either globally or with an improved field calculation? I've searched the official JDBC guide and Google and found nothing.

For example, what would help is if using a calculated field I can somehow determine that data was changed not through the FM solution, but through JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this question in the future:

The solution is actually fairly simple, modifying the code snippet I posted to check for the account name instead of a global variable. As I have made a special user for JDBC access, that works well.